# Can't install Ubuntu on Lenovo Windows 10 laptop

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation, windows-10

I'm trying and failing to install Ubuntu on my Windows 10 Lenovo Thinkpad.

There's two hard drives, I'm trying to install Linux on the second (though either HDD would be great). I've an SSD (C:/) and a SATA drive (D:/), both working on Windows and both internal

The install Ubuntu process itself fails. Trying Ubuntu, it starts up OK. But when I open 'Install Ubuntu' from the desktop, that also fails. It pops up saying I don't have enough space. When I try and edit mount points it just fails with an internal error every time.

I ran Ubuntu boot-repair and the results are here: https://paste.ubuntu.com/26475540/

I took a photo of the messages that popped up before the "Try" or "install" Ubuntu boot menu:

`failed to claim resource 1`
`nouveau failed to create kernel channel`

[image]

I would really, really appreciate some help. I just want to say goodbye to Windows forever!

If possible, I would replace Windows entirely. I can't be confident Ubuntu will work yet though.

I've also attached a photo of my hard disk partitions on the Windows side - to prove there is unallocated space.

[image: See hard disk partitions].

I ran commands as requested: 'sudo lsblk -f' and 'sudo lsblk -m'

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo lsblk -f
NAME   FSTYPE   LABEL UUID                                 MOUNTPOINT
loop0  squashfs                                            /rofs
sda                                                        
└─sda1 vfat     UUI   11E9-286A                            /cdrom
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo lsblk -m
NAME    SIZE OWNER GROUP MODE
loop0   1.4G root  disk  brw-rw----
sda    28.9G root  disk  brw-rw----
└─sda1 28.9G root  disk  brw-rw----
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$
```

Comment: "Trying Ubuntu, it starts up OK." Please try Ubuntu again, and from a terminal window, run the following commands (to show what drives and partitions that Ubuntu can see), `sudo lsblk -f` ; `sudo lsblk -m` ; `sudo parted -ls` ; `df` Edit the original question, add the output and indent each line 4 spaces to render the output as 'code'.

Comment: Ubuntu sees only the live drive, does not see any other drive. What are the other drives (the HDDs), what brand name and model, and how are they connected, internally or if externally, what external box (brand name and model)?

Comment: Apologies, a bit late in the day so my question was worded wrongly. The drives are actually all internal. 

I've an SSD (C:/) and a SATA drive (D:/), both working on Windows and both internal

Comment: I think the drive Ubuntu is seeing is just the 32gb memory stick

Comment: Are your disks in RAID mode? You would need to switch to AHCI mode in UEFI settings if that's the case.

Comment: Yes, the live drive that Ubuntu runs from (and sees) is  the 32gb memory stick.

Comment: Looking good people!  That tip on the AHCI mode vs UEFI mode definitely got me past the "does not recognise internal HDD" issue.

I followed this link https://hetmanrecovery.com/recovery_news/how-to-enable-ahci-mode-for-sata-in-the-bios-without-reinstalling-windows.htm which helped me make that change.

Updating now. If it works I will answer my own question and give credit to you as it might help others. 

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @muru and @sudodus in the comments above.

My Ubuntu install from a USB stick was failing - an error about a lack of space available.

The two internal hard drives were not getting recognised when installing.

This is now rememedied as per changing UEFI settings to AHCI mode.

I used this link: [How to change BIOS UEFI settings to AHCI mode](https://hetmanrecovery.com/recovery_news/how-to-enable-ahci-mode-for-sata-in-the-bios-without-reinstalling-windows.htm)